# Error: Cannot find module './routes/product.js' Require stack: - /app/index.js

Tags: javascript

today im deploying my server folder to railway, and when deploying i encounter error `Error: Cannot find module './routes/product.js' Require stack: - /app/index.js`. My index.js is not inside app folder and located in src/index. Why did this error happened, is there any problem in my application ?? btw im only getting error when trying to deploy the app, if i run it localy its working fine.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1102666761716891839/image.png

index.js :

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 5000;
const dbConnect = require("./db/dbConnect");
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const MemoryStore = require('memorystore')(session)
const dotenv =  require("dotenv");


dotenv.config();

dbConnect();

app.set('trust proxy', 1)

app.use(
  cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://e-commerce-production-25ef.up.railway.app"], 
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus : 200
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(session({
  cookie : {
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  },
  name: "keyId",
  store: new MemoryStore({
    checkPeriod: 86400000
  }),
  secret: 'subscribe',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false
}))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000", "https://e-commerce-production-25ef.up.railway.app");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});


const authRoute = require("./routes/auth.js");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user.js");
const producttRoute = require("./routes/product.js");
const cartRoute = require("./routes/cart.js");
const orderRoute = require("./routes/order.js");
const stripeRoute = require("./routes/stripe.js");

app.use(authRoute);
app.use(userRoute);
app.use(producttRoute);
app.use(cartRoute);
app.use(orderRoute);
app.use(stripeRoute);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

routes/product.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { verifyToken, verifyTokenAndAuthorization, verifyTokenAndAdmin } = require("./verifyToken");
const Product = require("../models/Product");


const addProduct = async (req, res) => {

    const newProduct = new Product(req.body)

    try {
        const saveProduct = await newProduct.save();
        res.status(200).json(saveProduct);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

}

const updateProduct = async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        const updatedProduct = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.params.id,
          {
            $set: req.body,
          },
          { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedProduct);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }

}

const deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
  
    try {
        await Product.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json("Product has been deleted..");
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
}

const getProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
        
        res.status(200).json(product);
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
}

const getAllProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const queryNew = req.query.new;
    const queryCategory = req.query.category;

    try {
        let products;

        if(queryNew) {
            products = await Product.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1}).limit(5);
        } else if (queryCategory) {
            products = await Product.find({categories: {
                $in: [queryCategory],
            },
        });
        } else {
            products = await Product.find({});
        }
  
        res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
}

router.post("/product/add", verifyTokenAndAdmin, addProduct);
router.put("/product/update/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, updateProduct);
router.delete("/product/delete/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, deleteProduct);
router.get("/product/find/:id", getProduct);
router.get("/product/all", getAllProduct);

module.exports = router;
```